# UCK error extracting gfxboot-theme

Tags: 15.04, uck

I want to add a few packages to the LiveCD that I use often. Currently the most up-to-date tool for this appears to be Ubuntu Customization Kit. When I try to run the application, it doesn't work and fails. It appears to be related to gfxboot.

Relevant terminal output:

```
Preparing build environment...
Running build process...
Build (/usr/bin/uck-gui ) started at 2015-10-04 17:15:04
[sudo] password for ev1l0rd: 
>> Ubuntu Customization Kit 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 15.04, 3.19.0-30-generic x86_64
Starting CD remastering on  zo okt 4 17:15:09 CEST 2015
Customization dir=/home/ev1l0rd/tmp/customization-scripts
Mounting ISO image...
mount: /dev/loop0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
Unpacking ISO image...
Unmounting ISO image...
Mounting SquashFS image...
Unpacking SquashFS image...
Unmounting SquashFS image...
Creating apt cache...
Creating root home...
Mounting /proc
Mounting /sys
Mounting /dev/pts
Mounting /tmp
Mounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root-home
Mounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-apt-cache
Mounting /run
Mounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/customization-scripts
Copying fstab/mtab...
Creating DBUS uuid...
Deactivating initctl...
mv: cannot stat '/sbin/initctl': No such file or directory
Deactivating update-grub...
Deactivating grub-probe...
Hacking grub-probe postinst/postrm...
Remembering kernel update state...
>> Customizing: Ubuntu 15.04, 3.19.0-15-generic x86_64
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security InRelease
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security Release [63.5 kB]
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid Release [217 kB]
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main amd64 Packages [120 kB]
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted amd64 Packages [10.4 kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe amd64 Packages [57.1 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [5195 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/main Translation-en [63.4 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/multiverse Translation-en [2246 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/restricted Translation-en [2607 B]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com vivid-security/universe Translation-en [35.3 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates Release [63.5 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main amd64 Packages [1364 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted amd64 Packages [15.4 kB]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe amd64 Packages [6485 kB]
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse amd64 Packages [134 kB]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/main Translation-en [793 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/restricted Translation-en
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid/universe Translation-en [4456 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main amd64 Packages [208 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [13.1 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe amd64 Packages [111 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [5195 B]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/main Translation-en [102 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2246 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/restricted Translation-en [2969 B]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com vivid-updates/universe Translation-en [65.3 kB]
Fetched 14.4 MB in 15s (946 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Installing language packs ()...
Done
Restoring kernel update state...
Reactivating initctl...
mv: cannot stat '/sbin/initctl.uck_blocked': No such file or directory
Reactivating update-grub...
Reactivating grub-probe...
Reactivating grub-probe postinst/postrm...
Removing /home/username directory...
Removing generated machine uuid...
Removing generated fstab/mtab...
Removing crash reports...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/tmp/customization-scripts...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/tmp...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/sys...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/run...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/root...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/proc...
Unmounting /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/remaster-root/dev/pts...
Cleaning up temporary directories...
Running ISO customization script /home/ev1l0rd/tmp/customization-scripts/customize_iso...
--2015-10-04 17:20:02--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources.gz
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.15, 91.189.91.24, 91.189.91.23, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.15|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1357649 (1,3M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘/tmp/tmp.OcTN93PAPA/Sources.gz’

     0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  3%  270K 5s
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  7%  530K 3s
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 11% 3,98M 2s
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 15%  414K 2s
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 18%  639K 2s
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 22% 1,45M 2s
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 26%  666K 2s
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 30%  614K 2s
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 33% 2,05M 1s
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 37%  629K 1s
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 41%  713K 1s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 45% 1,36M 1s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 49%  687K 1s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 52% 1,59M 1s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 56%  638K 1s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 60% 2,02M 1s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 64%  665K 1s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 67% 2,40M 1s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 71%  633K 1s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 75% 1,06M 0s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 79%  933K 0s
  1050K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 82% 1,19M 0s
  1100K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 86% 1,28M 0s
  1150K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 90% 1,35M 0s
  1200K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 94% 1,20M 0s
  1250K .......... .......... .......... .......... .......... 98% 1,09M 0s
  1300K .......... .......... .....                           100% 1,36M=1,6s

2015-10-04 17:20:04 (834 KB/s) - ‘/tmp/tmp.OcTN93PAPA/Sources.gz’ saved [1357649/1357649]

--2015-10-04 17:20:04--  http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu/
Resolving archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.24, 91.189.92.200, 91.189.91.14, ...
Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com (archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 6462 (6,3K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

     0K ......                                                100% 8,64M=0,001s

2015-10-04 17:20:04 (8,64 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [6462/6462]

tar (child): *.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
Unable to extract gfxboot-theme-ubuntu source package

** (zenity:2489): WARNING **: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
Build ended at 2015-10-04 17:20:16
```

Any idea for a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if you manually go to [the link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gfxboot-theme-ubuntu/) to the file downloaded before the error, you can see that at a point all archives are .deb and no more .tar.xz. So, the /usr/lib/uck/customization-profiles/localized_cd/customize_iso has to be changed in order to expand the new file format, and find the files in its new path.

Fully solved [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699282/ubuntu-customization-kit-vs-ubuntu-mate-15-10), with the full script text.
It has been updated to the last archives format. Plus miscs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/491753)

Comment: Ok, answer has been expanded.

Answer (score 1):

[The bug is rather common and there is a fix avaiable on Launchpad in the form of a .diff file.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/uck/+bug/1463583) By applying the patch manually it worked. `patch` didn't work properly for some reason.

It is caused by the package receiving a different compression between the update from 14.04 to 14.10.